How are eigenvalues and singular values related to inner products?
I have been reading this paper on non-reversible Markov chains and I am confused by the basic setup. My understanding of spectral values/vectors is very basic, i.e. an eigenvector $v$ of a matrix $A$ and its associated value $\lambda$ are defined by $Av=\lambda v$. Now I have come across the following.

Let $X_0, X_1,\ldots$ be a time-homogeneous stationary Markov chain on a finite state space $\mathscr{S}$. Let $P$ be the transition matrix of the chain and $L = I − P$ be the generator. Let $\mu$ be an invariant probability measure of our chain, such that $\mu(x) > 0$ for all $x \in \mathscr{S}$. The measure $\mu$ defines an inner product on $\mathbb{C}^S$ in the usual way: For two functions $f, g : \mathscr S → \mathbb C,$ $$\langle f, g\rangle := \sum_{x\in\mathscr S} f (x)\ \overline{g(x)}\ \mu(x).$$


Definition (1.1) We will denote the norm induced by this inner product by $‖ · ‖$. Definition 1.1. We define the spectral gap of the chain, $\gamma$, to be the $\textbf{second-smallest singular value of L with respect to the above inner product on $\mathbb{C}^S$}$ (counting singular values with multiplicities), and call τ := 1/γ the relaxation time of the chain.

(Chatterjee, Sourav."Spectral gap of nonreversible Markov chains." arXiv preprint arXiv:2310.10876 (2023).)
My question again is very basic in that I just need some intuition for the relation of the inner product and the singular values in question. Are these SV different from those I would get from straight up computing them as the solutions to $ LL^*v=\sigma^2v$?
